# Can not add criteria api predicate in Kotlin, getting Type interface failed error

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, criteria-api

I am having very annoying issue that i can't solve, and i guess i am missing something really straight forward, because i already have working code in Java.

Basically what i have is this:

```
class ConfigurationSpecification(
        private var list: MutableList<SearchCriteria> = mutableListOf()
) : Specification<Configuration> {
    override fun toPredicate(root: Root<Configuration>, query: CriteriaQuery<*>, builder: CriteriaBuilder): Predicate? {
        val predicates: MutableList<Predicate> = mutableListOf()

        for (criteria in list) {
            if (criteria.operation == "EQUALS") {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(criteria.key), criteria.value)) <- NOT WORKING root.get(criteria.key) this is making issue
            }
        }

        return builder.and(predicates[0])
    }
}
```

The code is really straight forward, but from some reason Kotlin is complaining about it, error that i get is this:

> Error:(19, 51) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information
>   to infer parameter Y in fun  get(p0: String!): Path!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

And this is working java code:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue())); <- working with Java
```

Any experienced Kotlin person who knows workaround for this error ? I have seen some other people had similar issues, but i can not fix this based on answers that i seen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From docs:

> < Y> Path< Y> get(String attributeName)
>
> Create a path corresponding to the referenced attribute.
>
> Note: Applications using the string-based API may need to specify the
>   type resulting from the get operation in order to avoid the use of
>   Path variables.

To fix your error, you need to specify generic type explicitly, because Kotlin compiler can't infer it from context:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get</* type of criteria.value */>(criteria.key), criteria.value))
```